# Running a "usually not-virtualized Win 10" under Linux KVM : is it a good idea?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, linux-kvm

My desktop machine has the following setup:

- First SSD : 512GiB for a Debian 10 Linux.
- Second SSD : 256GiB for a Windows 10 installation.

I used to switch OS by rebooting when i need it.

Today, for a quick test, i would have like to launch Windows 10 directly from SSD #2 (aka `/dev/sdb`  under Linux) using KVM under Debian... so that i can have both WIN10 and Linux at the same time.

I know that a regular debian install is totally able to boot on both virtualized or bare-metal setup.
But Windows 10 looks to be really sticked to the hardware it has been first installed on.

So would it be a good idea ? 
Would WIN10 boot up correctly on the new, virtualized, hardware ? 
If so, would it be able to revert to the bare-metal hardware smoothly ? 
Won't it cause "licencing" issues ?

I really don't want to reinstall from scratch my Windows and the games, adobe software, etc... on it. That's why i prefer to ask for feedback ;-)

Comment: If it will works and what restrictions will remain can only answer a real world test. hence, make a full backup image of your second SSD and give it a try. Most likely you will dissatisfied anyway as usually hardware acceleration does not work or not as reliable as you expect. You may also run in a license problem if Windows was pre-installed on your system and therefore the virtualized Windows can't access the BIOS with the license.

Answer (score 0):

A license recognition depends, what type of license is used: OEM (license won’t probably work), RETAIL (reactivation may be required) or Microsoft Account License (should work automatically).

The VM performance certainly will be slower in compare with baremetal especially for GPU-dependent applications/ games.

If there is enough free space on “debian” SSD, you can test performance of Windows 10 VM without removing it from second SSD, so no reinstallation will be required. Convert physical disk to qcow2 image with [starwind v2v](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-v2v-converter) converter, create VM with corresponding CPU and RAM (RAM can be decreased) and attached converted disk.